# FullCalendar com Integração Google

Tags: c#, fullcalendar, google-calendar

Galera, eu já usei esse componente antes em um outro projeto, agora eu tinha interesse em utilizar a integração com o calendário do google. Alguém já utilizou o FullCalendar https://fullcalendar.io/ com integração com o google.

Eu andei lendo a documentação, e pelo que eu entendi, para funcionar, eu deveria deixar o meu calendário publico, assim, até para um pesquisa o calendário estaria disponível. É assim mesmo? Alguém está utilizando ou já utilizou?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Devo excluir ou arquivar essa pergunta, visto que não tive nenhuma resposta ou comentário?

Comment: Não. Se ela ficar sem votos nem resposta por muito tempo, o sistema exclui sozinho. Se quiser acrescentar mais detalhes, pode atrair atenção para a pergunta.